# Find all minimal elements in a list or set as weighted by a function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set, min

If I want to find *a* minimum of a list or set x as given by some function f on that set, I can use convenient oneliners such as

```
min(x,key=f)
```

(4.91 µs)

While for a 'pure' min function, it doesn't make sense to return more than one element in most cases (since all of them are the same, and for sets there is only one), if you choose the minimum according to some function, you will often want to know all the elements for which it was minimal.

In other words, I'm looking for a short, concise and fast function, that allows me to return all minimal elements according to some weighting functing, which preferably works for both lists and sets (and returns the the result in the data type of the input).

For lists, the fastest thing I've managed to write is

```
def allmin(x,f):
    vals = map(f, x)
    minval = min(vals)
    return [x[i] for i,e in enumerate(vals) if e==minval]
```

6.73 µs

However, this is far from optimal and doesn't work for sets. First of all, when mapping, all the function values are in memory at some point, so that's the best time to determine the minima instead of looking at it again, which is illustrated in the fact that this is already 50% slower although no additional computations (except for list construction) should have to be performed compared to the single-min example. The only comparable thing for sets I've managed to write is

```
def allmin(x,f):
    vals = [(f(e), e) for e in x]
    minval = min(vals)[0]
    return {e for val,e in vals if val==minval}
```

8.44 µs (7.29 µs with list comprehension for the list version)

Any way I can get the performance for lists to around the performance for the better allmin version for lists, and best of all, somewhere near the performance of min(x,key=f)?

(To illustrate and for the timings, I assumed

```
f = lambda x: (x-4.5)**2
x = random.choice([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13],{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13}])
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know that number of minimal values, then a simple single pass approach is to keep a running list of minimal values for the lowest weight seen so far:

```
def minimal(iterable, func):
    'Return a list of minimal values according to a weighting function'
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        x = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return []
    lowest_values = [x]
    lowest_weight = func(x)
    for x in it:
        weight = func(x)
        if weight == lowest_weight:
            lowest_values.append(x)
        elif weight < lowest_weight:
            lowest_values = []
            lowest_weight = weight
    return lowest_values
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> s = {'abc', 'defg', 'hij', 'kl', 'mno', 'qr', 'stuv', 'wx', 'yz'}
>>> minimal(s, len)
['qr', 'kl', 'yz', 'wx']
```

Alternatively, if you know in advance how many minimal values there are, the [*heapq.nsmallest*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) function will solve the problem directly and efficiently.  For the *k* smallest of *n* values, it make *n* calls to your weighting function and uses memory proportional to *k* (i.e. it is very cache efficient):

```
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> s = {'abc', 'defg', 'hij', 'kl', 'mno', 'qr', 'stuv', 'wx', 'yz'}
>>> nsmallest(4, s, key=len)
['qr', 'kl', 'yz', 'wx']
```

Comment: Ugh, this is basically the same as my final algorithm. Comparing weight > lowest_weight first then continuing if satisfied will lead to a further speed up because on average more elements are likely to hit the condition. In your current code, if weight > lowest_weight, two unnecessary comparisons are executed.

Comment: Ugh, two people can come up with similar answers -- it is essentially just a minor modification of the code for *min()*.  Also, I don't see any mention of *heapq.nsmallest()*.   Anyway, I think we've exhausted the interesting solution space for this simple little problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently spending Θ(n) to apply `f()` over all elements, then another Θ(n) to find the minimum among them, then finally another Θ(n) to find all elements that are equal to the minimum. In short, you are spending 3 x Θ(n), where `n` is the size of the input list.

You can theoretically do this in 2 x Θ(n) by spending Θ(n) to find the minimum while applying `f()`, then spending another Θ(n) to retrieve all minimum elements. However, there seems to be a faster way, where you spend Θ(n) for applying `f()` and finding the minimum, but only spend `O(n)` when retrieving all minimum elements. (Note that in the worst case, O(n) is no different to Θ(n). For the below algorithm, this worst case occurs when all elements in the list are the same, or the list is sorted in the reverse order.)

```
def allmin(x,f):
    minVal = 9999999999999999999999999
    mapped = []
    for a in x:
        mapVal = f(a)
        if mapVal <= minVal:
            minVal = mapVal
            mapped.append((a, mapVal))
    return [a for (a,m) in mapped if m == minVal]
```

My own time measurements show roughly 20% time improvement over your `allmin()` method for a list of integers ranging from 0 to 100.

For very large input lists, it may be worth sampling a few elements to start off with so that you can provide a better initial value for minVal (rather than the trivial initialization to a very large value).

========================================= EDIT =========================================

Here's a version that provides a further 5~10% speed up. The speed up comes from the observation that once a new minimum value is found, all previously stored mapped values can be discarded. Thus the final O(n) for retrieving the minimum value is no longer required, and the whole algorithms takes 1 x Θ(n) to run.

```
def newallmin(x,f):
    minVal = f(x[-1])
    minList = []
    for a in x:
        mapVal = f(a)
        if mapVal > minVal:
            continue
        if mapVal < minVal:
            minVal = mapVal
            minList = [a]
        else: # mapVal == minVal
            minList.append(a)
    return minList
```

I've been performing time measurements with a list of size 10,000,000 with all elements ranging from 0 to 100.